# Using responsive grid system, but my 2column images won't fit/centre?

Tags: html, css, grid, alignment

http://www.alinewbury.com/3bosquet.html

The link above will show you that my first four vertical images in the responsive grid system do not align or centre on the page properly. My boyfriend opened the page and said they were stacking instead of sitting next to each other. Can anyone identify the problem for me please?

Dimensions are 600x848pixels

Comment: this is an issue to do with percentages and whole pixels. you will either need to look at adjusting how your grid works (remove margin from columns, and instead look at adding inner padding [using box-sizing] to give your columns guttering). or as a hack around.. i found reducing your left padding on `.col` down to `4%` instead of `5%` fixed the alignment [line 28 of 4cols.css]

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap grid system 
its easy to implement with many options too 
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/